# How to allow Null as the default value in ContainerBuilder?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a `Parent` class that can accept `IChild` class that can be null as a default.

Like:

```
public class Parent
{
    private IChild _child; //Nullable object.
    public Parent(IChild child) //child can be null.
    {
        this._child = child;
    }
}
```

When I uses the Parent class like:

```
var parent = new Parent(null);
```

Everything works fine.

But when I uses the `ContainerBuilder` (autofac) like:

```
var cb = new ContainerBuilder();
cb.RegisterType<Parent>();
cb.RegisterInstance((IChild) null);
using (var builder = cb.Build())
{
    var builder = cb.Resolve<Parent>();
}
```

I'm getting the general error:

> system.argumentnullexception value cannot be null

Looks like that dependency injection does not work well with passing null reference as a default, **any suggestions for a clean work arounds**?

Comment: you don't need to register for null, just resolve it and see it should return null probably

Comment: This looks like you're using Autofac, correct? You should specify this in your question, because it makes a difference.

Comment: If you make a default constructor, `public Parent() : this(null) {}`, everything should work very smoothly. Otherwise, you could tell the container to populate the parameter like so: `cb.RegisterType<Parent>().WithParameter("child", null);`

Comment: gnud, thanks I'lll try that. (Is there any difference regarding passing null as default value between `autofac` and Unity`? because if so, my question is not duplicate.

Comment: Referenced duplicate was for Unity not Autofac. These are different products, so this is not a duplicate of that specific question. Reopened.

Comment: Closed in favour of an autofac dupe.

Comment: Prevent injecting null values alltogether into constructors of components. You should instead inject a default, empty implementation, a.k.a. a [Null Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern).